# bitcoincore connect

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I have a problem with bitcoin node is that when I want to get out of the full node bitcoin server.

I ran this method and it does not work

```
curl \
  --user myusername \
  --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0", "id":"curltest", "method":"getnewaddress", "params":[]]' \
  -H 'content-type : text / plain; ' \
  http://ip server for node:8332/
```

---

Answer edited to add:

Error message

```
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Config file

```
erver=1 
aemon=1 
rpcallowip=ip exchange rpc
allowip=127.0.0.1 
rpcport=8332 
rpcuser=xxx 
rpcpassword=xxxxxx
wallet=/home/user/.bitcoin/wallets/coininx/wallet/dat 
walletdir=/home/user/.bitcoin/wallets
```

Comment: This question in my opinion is not clear, because your question show only the terminal command, you run the bitcoin node on your device? what is your bitcoind conf?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it does not work"* - were there some error messages - if so what exactly.

Comment: This is my config file for bitcoin

erver=1
aemon=1
rpcallowip=ip exchange
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxxxxx
wallet=/home/user/.bitcoin/wallets/coininx/wallet/dat
walletdir=/home/user/.bitcoin/wallets/

Comment: and error messages :
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Comment: Is bitcoind running?

Comment: Does your config file really have `erver` not `server` and `eamon` not `daemon`?

Comment: The first sentence in this question is very confusing. Could you perhaps read that again and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If your bitcoin daemon isn't running because of a mistake in the configuration file then you won't be able to connect to that daemon.

If the daemon is started automatically, you should be able to check for error messages in the system log.

It should also be possible to start the daemon manually to see any error messages concerning the configuration file.